# Weird translation in One Piece Episode 132?

Tags: one-piece, japanese-language

In One Piece's Episode 132, when Luffy tries to apologize to Nami for messing up her drawn map, from what I can get (I may be wrong), Nami (gets frustrated and) says (in romaji),

> Gomen de sundara, kaigun wa iranai wa

The translation in the anime is shown as:

> If sorry was all it took, the Marines wouldn't be after us!

This translation seems a bit off; it seems out of the context. Although "kaigun" does mean Navy but I think from what I understand, Nami wanted to say,

> I don't care if you are sorry!

Following this sentence, Nami says "Just get out!".

I wanted to know if my doubts are right and whether the translation is really a bit off. I think the word "kaigun" can be "kaigo" which can mean nursing or care but I am not sure.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say the translation is off.

Nami is trying to convey that simply saying 'sorry' is not going to resolve the issue at hand.
Similar to how saying sorry to the marines would not make the crew any less of a wanted criminal.

Hence `I don't care if you are sorry!` doesn't really covers what she tries to convey. She may still care about him being sorry, but in the end it's only a cold comfort. It will not fix or rectify the situation.

Or in the context of the episode, just saying sorry is not magically going to repair or fix the damages done to the map. Which she just put a lot of effort into making.

So something along the lines of `Being sorry is not going to fix this map!` would probably better reflect what Nami was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

If your transcription is accurate, I'll break down the translation.

ごめんで住んだら、海軍は入らないは。

住む "to live, to abide" -> 住んだら "if [it] was to live/abide"

Here the verb 住む is acting on ごめん, the apology.

The entire first part,

ごめんで住んだら "if 'sorry' was to abide" -> "if 'sorry' (worked/did the trick/was enough of an apology)"

That first part is pretty dead on, as you say they translated it as "If 'sorry' was all it took,"

Now the second part,

海軍は入らないは

海軍 is Navy or Marines, literally "sea military." I would translate it as whatever the show calls the Navy faction. Marines, I guess?

入る "to get in/go in/come in/flow into/put in, ..." -> 入らない "does not get in/go in/..."

commonly used in phrases referring to actions like "I poured water into the cup," it is used for more meanings than just these, by invoking context. In this case, the water is the Marines, and the cup is the area around Nami or their ship.

"The Navy does not come in" -> "The Marines wouldn't be coming (towards us/to this place/after us)"

I think the translation here is exactly correct. I'm surprised because a lot of times translators add or remove meaning from the original, which usually doesn't change the content very much.

Of course, if you wanted to make an artistic interpretation and judge the words based on Nami's expression and tone, the words might be angrier, but then it would also change the original meaning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this amazing step by step translation! I was looking for the exact translation and you helped me with that. Thanks again! :-D

Comment: Actually, in this context, すむ should be 済む, not 住む. Also, いらない should be 要らない, not 入らない. Example: [ごめんで済むなら警察は要らない](https://enpedia.rxy.jp/wiki/%E3%81%94%E3%82%81%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E6%B8%88%E3%82%80%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E8%AD%A6%E5%AF%9F%E3%81%AF%E8%A6%81%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Comment: @AkiTanaka, Thanks for that link! :-D And I think you are right about すむ  and いらない. The words which you have given (済む and 要らない) indeed seems to be exact. Japanese is undoubtedly not an easy language; it has so many different words with different meanings for same pronunciation, but it's equally interesting! :-)